# Runtime error (3020): How to add information to a new record?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get a runtime error (3020) when trying to add information to a new record.

It errors out on the line: `rs2!PlanTitle.Value = RWPSheetvalues(96)`

```
Private Sub ImportRWPData_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim File As Field
    Dim Location As String
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("rwpT")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("AIP&BOP")
    Set File = rs.Fields("File")
    Dim xls     As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb     As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks     As Excel.Worksheet
    Set xls = New Excel.Application
    'Declare variables for column values in RWP spreadsheets
    Dim orgSheetCol(7) As String
        orgSheetCol(0) = "$A$" 'Auto Isolation Point
        orgSheetCol(1) = "$D$" 'Customer Minutes Lost
        orgSheetCol(2) = "$H$" '% work plan fix
        orgSheetCol(3) = "$E$" 'Customers in Incident Sustained
        orgSheetCol(4) = "$C3$" 'Plan Title
        orgSheetCol(5) = "$B33$" 'Years of Data
        orgSheetCol(6) = "$B37$" 'Annual Improved CML
    'Declare variables for cell values attained from RWP spreadsheets
     Dim RWPSheetvalues(100) As String
         RWPSheetvalues(0) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 1
         RWPSheetvalues(1) = "" 'CML for Point 1
         RWPSheetvalues(2) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(3) = "" 'CI For Point 1
         RWPSheetvalues(4) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 2
         RWPSheetvalues(5) = "" 'CML for Point 2
         RWPSheetvalues(6) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(7) = "" 'CI For Point 2
         RWPSheetvalues(8) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 3
         RWPSheetvalues(9) = "" 'CML for Point 3
         RWPSheetvalues(10) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(11) = "" 'CI For Point 3
         RWPSheetvalues(12) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 4
         RWPSheetvalues(13) = "" 'CML for Point 4
         RWPSheetvalues(14) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(15) = "" 'CI For Point 4
         RWPSheetvalues(16) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 5
         RWPSheetvalues(17) = "" 'CML for Point 5
         RWPSheetvalues(18) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(19) = "" 'CI For Point 5
         RWPSheetvalues(20) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 6
         RWPSheetvalues(21) = "" 'CML for Point 6
         RWPSheetvalues(22) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(23) = "" 'CI For Point 6
         RWPSheetvalues(24) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 7
         RWPSheetvalues(25) = "" 'CML for Point 7
         RWPSheetvalues(26) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(27) = "" 'CI For Point 7
         RWPSheetvalues(28) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 8
         RWPSheetvalues(29) = "" 'CML for Point 8
         RWPSheetvalues(30) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(31) = "" 'CI For Point 8
         RWPSheetvalues(32) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 9
         RWPSheetvalues(33) = "" 'CML for Point 9
         RWPSheetvalues(34) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(35) = "" 'CI For Point 9
         RWPSheetvalues(36) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 10
         RWPSheetvalues(37) = "" 'CML for Point 10
         RWPSheetvalues(38) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(39) = "" 'CI For Point 10
         RWPSheetvalues(40) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 11
         RWPSheetvalues(41) = "" 'CML for Point 11
         RWPSheetvalues(42) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(43) = "" 'CI For Point 11
         RWPSheetvalues(44) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 12
         RWPSheetvalues(45) = "" 'CML for Point 12
         RWPSheetvalues(46) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(47) = "" 'CI For Point 12
         RWPSheetvalues(48) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 13
         RWPSheetvalues(49) = "" 'CML for Point 13
         RWPSheetvalues(50) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(51) = "" 'CI For Point 13
         RWPSheetvalues(52) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 14
         RWPSheetvalues(53) = "" 'CML for Point 14
         RWPSheetvalues(54) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(55) = "" 'CI For Point 14
         RWPSheetvalues(56) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 15
         RWPSheetvalues(57) = "" 'CML for Point 15
         RWPSheetvalues(58) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(59) = "" 'CI For Point 15
         RWPSheetvalues(60) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 16
         RWPSheetvalues(61) = "" 'CML for Point 16
         RWPSheetvalues(62) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(63) = "" 'CI For Point 16
         RWPSheetvalues(64) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 17
         RWPSheetvalues(65) = "" 'CML for Point 17
         RWPSheetvalues(66) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(67) = "" 'CI For Point 17
         RWPSheetvalues(68) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 18
         RWPSheetvalues(69) = "" 'CML for Point 18
         RWPSheetvalues(70) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(71) = "" 'CI For Point 18
         RWPSheetvalues(72) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 19
         RWPSheetvalues(73) = "" 'CML for Point 19
         RWPSheetvalues(74) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(75) = "" 'CI For Point 19
         RWPSheetvalues(76) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 20
         RWPSheetvalues(77) = "" 'CML for Point 20
         RWPSheetvalues(78) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(79) = "" 'CI For Point 20
         RWPSheetvalues(80) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 21
         RWPSheetvalues(81) = "" 'CML for Point 21
         RWPSheetvalues(82) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(83) = "" 'CI For Point 21
         RWPSheetvalues(84) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 22
         RWPSheetvalues(85) = "" 'CML for Point 22
         RWPSheetvalues(86) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(87) = "" 'CI For Point 22
         RWPSheetvalues(88) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 23
         RWPSheetvalues(89) = "" 'CML for Point 23
         RWPSheetvalues(90) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(91) = "" 'CI For Point 23
         RWPSheetvalues(92) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 24
         RWPSheetvalues(93) = "" 'CML for Point 24
         RWPSheetvalues(94) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
         RWPSheetvalues(95) = "" 'CI For Point 25
         RWPSheetvalues(96) = "" 'Plan Title
         RWPSheetvalues(97) = "" 'File Location
         RWPSheetvalues(98) = "" 'Years of Data
         RWPSheetvalues(99) = "" 'Annual Improved CML
     Dim cellstring As String
     Dim rowstring As String
     Dim rownumber As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim ii As Integer
     rowstring = CStr(rownumber)
     Dim Mycheck As String
     
     Do Until rs.EOF
         Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open(File, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
         Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Benefit of Plan")
         ii = 0
         For rownumber = 7 To 30
             rowstring = CStr(rownumber)
             For i = 0 To 3
                 cellstring = orgSheetCol(i) & rowstring
                 RWPSheetvalues(ii) = wks.Range(cellstring).Value
                 If RWPSheetvalues(ii) = "" Then
                     RWPSheetvalues(ii) = "0"
                 End If
                 Mycheck = VarType(RWPSheetvalues(ii))
                 ii = ii + 1
                 Dim x As String
             Next i
         Next rownumber
         RWPSheetvalues(96) = wks.Range("C3").Value
         RWPSheetvalues(97) = File
         RWPSheetvalues(98) = wks.Range("B33").Value
         RWPSheetvalues(99) = wks.Range("B37").Value
         wkb.Close False 'Close workbook.  False is so that it doesn't save
         tablecheck = DCount("PlanTitle", "AIP&BOP", "PlanTitle = '" & RWPSheetvalues(96) & "'") 'check AIP & BOP table to see if plan is already there
         If tablecheck = 0 Then
             rs2!PlanTitle.Value = RWPSheetvalues(96)
             rs2!FileLocation.Value = RWPSheetvalues(97)
             rs2!YearsofData.Value = RWPSheetvalues(98)
             rs2!AnnualImprovedCML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(99)
             rs2!AIP1.Value = RWPSheetvalues(0)
             rs2!AIP1CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(1)
             rs2!AIP1BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(2)
             rs2!AIP1CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(3)
             rs2!AIP2.Value = RWPSheetvalues(4)
             rs2!AIP2CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(5)
             rs2!AIP2BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(6)
             rs2!AIP2CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(7)
             rs2!AIP3.Value = RWPSheetvalues(8)
             rs2!AIP3CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(9)
             rs2!AIP3BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(10)
             rs2!AIP3CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(11)
             rs2!AIP4.Value = RWPSheetvalues(12)
             rs2!AIP4CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(13)
             rs2!AIP4BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(14)
             rs2!AIP4CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(15)
             rs2!AIP5.Value = RWPSheetvalues(16)
             rs2!AIP5CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(17)
             rs2!AIP5BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(18)
             rs2!AIP5CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(19)
             rs2!AIP6.Value = RWPSheetvalues(20)
             rs2!AIP6CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(21)
             rs2!AIP6BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(22)
             rs2!AIP6CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(23)
             rs2!AIP7.Value = RWPSheetvalues(24)
             rs2!AIP7CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(25)
             rs2!AIP7BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(26)
             rs2!AIP7CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(27)
             rs2!AIP8.Value = RWPSheetvalues(28)
             rs2!AIP9CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(29)
             rs2!AIP8BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(30)
             rs2!AIP8CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(31)
             rs2!AIP9.Value = RWPSheetvalues(32)
             rs2!AIP9CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(33)
             rs2!AIP9BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(34)
             rs2!AIP9CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(35)
             rs2!AIP10.Value = RWPSheetvalues(36)
             rs2!AIP10CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(37)
             rs2!AIP10BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(38)
             rs2!AIP10CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(39)
             rs2!AIP11.Value = RWPSheetvalues(40)
             rs2!AIP11CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(41)
             rs2!AIP11BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(42)
             rs2!AIP11CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(43)
             rs2!AIP12.Value = RWPSheetvalues(44)
             rs2!AIP12CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(45)
             rs2!AIP12BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(46)
             rs2!AIP12CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(47)
             rs2!AIP13.Value = RWPSheetvalues(48)
             rs2!AIP13CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(49)
             rs2!AIP13BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(50)
             rs2!AIP13CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(51)
             rs2!AIP14.Value = RWPSheetvalues(52)
             rs2!AIP14CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(53)
             rs2!AIP14BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(54)
             rs2!AIP14CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(55)
             rs2!AIP15.Value = RWPSheetvalues(56)
             rs2!AIP15CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(57)
             rs2!AIP15BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(58)
             rs2!AIP15CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(59)
             rs2!AIP16.Value = RWPSheetvalues(60)
             rs2!AIP16CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(61)
             rs2!AIP16BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(62)
             rs2!AIP16CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(63)
             rs2!AIP17.Value = RWPSheetvalues(64)
             rs2!AIP17CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(65)
             rs2!AIP17BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(66)
             rs2!AIP17CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(67)
             rs2!AIP18.Value = RWPSheetvalues(68)
             rs2!AIP18CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(69)
             rs2!AIP18BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(70)
             rs2!AIP18CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(71)
             rs2!AIP19.Value = RWPSheetvalues(72)
             rs2!AIP9CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(73)
             rs2!AIP19BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(74)
             rs2!AIP19CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(75)
             rs2!AIP20.Value = RWPSheetvalues(76)
             rs2!AIP20CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(77)
             rs2!AIP20BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(78)
             rs2!AIP20CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(79)
             rs2!AIP21.Value = RWPSheetvalues(80)
             rs2!AIP21CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(81)
             rs2!AIP21BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(82)
             rs2!AIP21CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(83)
             rs2!AIP22.Value = RWPSheetvalues(84)
             rs2!AIP22CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(85)
             rs2!AIP22BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(86)
             rs2!AIP22CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(87)
             rs2!AIP23.Value = RWPSheetvalues(88)
             rs2!AIP23CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(89)
             rs2!AIP23BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(90)
             rs2!AIP23CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(91)
             rs2!AIP24.Value = RWPSheetvalues(92)
             rs2!AIP24CML.Value = RWPSheetvalues(93)
             rs2!AIP24BOP.Value = RWPSheetvalues(94)
             rs2!AIP24CI.Value = RWPSheetvalues(95)
             rs2.Update
         End If
         rs.MoveNext

     Loop
     rs.Close
     rs2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing

```
rs2.AddNew
```

before setting its column values.